# Can IPython console print Pandas dataframes with horizontal scroll bars using Python IDE Spyder 5?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, spyder

Is it possible to print large Pandas dataframes in the IPython console with a horizontal scroll bar, using Spyder 5 IDE? The IPython console tries to fit large dataframes to its window size which makes the data hard to read because of overlapping columns.

[image: IPython console: fitted dataframe]

Comment: How about just reading/opening the df from the Variable explorer tab?

Comment: Thank you very much queste. You can observe variables in Spyders’s variable explorer. A really cool feature. Anyway, I have used to work with Visual Studio 2019 and PTVS. There you have a horizontal scroll bar in the IPython console on larger dataframes. Personally, I like this feature very much and hope it is available in the Spyder IDE as well. Maybe there is an option in the editor settings which I have not been able to find, yet.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) For now we wrap output in the console to avoid using a horizontal scrollbar (that choice was not taken by us and it was decided a long time ago). There's already an [issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/14120) about that, so we'll try to address it in a future version.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you very much for the information and the work that you do on Spyder. I like this tool. Happy weekend.

Comment: @Oyibo, thanks for your kind words!